# Negative Infinity or positive infinity in loss function in Regression

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, logistic-regression

My output is showing infinity or negative infinity for loss function. It should be 0 or 1.

```
w = np.random.randn(6)
x = np.random.randn(6)
b =1
z = np.dot(w,x) + b
# a is sigmoid 
a = 1/1+np.exp(-z)
loss_function = -(np.dot(a,np.log(y) + np.dot((1-a),np.log(1-y))))
```

in case of y when i am using any values for y. it shows

```
-inf
```

or
`inf`

Can Someone explain me this?

Comment: It's not possible to use _any_ value for `y`: `np.log(1-y)` implies that `1 - y > 0`, so `y < 1`. Are you passing `y` that is less than 1?

Comment: Please provide *some* value for which the issue occurs. For ``y=0.5``, I get a ``loss_function`` of ``0.6420817786893799``, ``-2363.635754984989``, ``-188.1582335139518``, ... (depending on ``w``, ``x``).

Comment: No first i tried with value of y as 0. but then i tried other values such as 1,2,....  for value less than zero it shows nan.

Comment: ``np.log(1-y)`` and ``np.log(y)`` implies that ``0 < y < 1`` should be respected. Are you sure the function should be defined for arbitrary values of ``y``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi try with value y=1, for y=0.5 it's working

Comment: ``y=1`` does not satisfy ``0 < y < 1``.

Comment: @ajay, you can't have `y >= 1` because then `1 - y` will be less than 0, and the logarithm of something not positive is not defined.

Comment: @ForceBru as this was loss function for predicted value and actual value. does that mean we can always have value for actual one between 0 and 1?

Comment: @ajay, [log_b(x)=y for any two positive real numbers b and x, where b is not equal to 1, is always a unique real number y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), so yes, as long as `0 < y < 1` (in _your_ code, not in this example), you'll get some real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the formula for the Cross Entropy loss function backward that's why you only get infinity.

Your true label `y` being either `0` or `1` this will never work, instead it's `a` that you should put in the log :

```
loss_function = -(np.dot(y,np.log(a) + np.dot((1-y),np.log(1-a))))
```

Comment: yeah, i got confused with forward and backward implementation.